# Checkbox disappears after adding additional input element inside div

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, pseudo-element

I am having a checkbox styled using pseudo element. It is working as expected using below html code . Image also added for reference. But when I add another input element just after the first input element, the checkbox circle disappears. The additional input element is added by webserver during runtime so it cannot be avoided. I am not sure how to fix it . Can someone please throw some light on it.

**Working Code**

```
<div class="fgt-sec">
  <input type="checkbox" name="cc" id="c2" />
  <label for="c2">
    <span></span>
  </label>
  <small>Yes, I understand and agree to the Terms & Conditions.</small>
</div>
                   <div class="checky-sec">
                    <div class="fgt-sec">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="cc" id="c1">
                        <label for="c1">
                            <span></span>
                        </label>
                        <small>Remember me</small>
                    </div><!--fgt-sec end-->
                    <a href="#" title="">Forgot Password?</a>
                </div>
```

[image]

**Not Working HTML Code after adding additional html input element**

```
    <div class="fgt-sec">
  <input type="checkbox" name="cc" id="c2" />
  <input type="hidden" name="test" />
  <label for="c2">
    <span></span>
  </label>
  <small>Yes, I understand and agree to the Terms & Conditions.</small>
</div>
```

**Circle Disappears**

[image]

**CSS Code**

```
      .fgt-sec {
        float: left;
      }
      .fgt-sec input[type="checkbox"] {
        display: none;
      }
      .fgt-sec label {
        float: left;
      }
      .fgt-sec input[type="checkbox"] ~ label span {
        display: inline-block;
        width: 15px;
        height: 15px;
        position: relative;
        border:1px solid #d2d2d2;
        -webkit-border-radius: 100px;
        -moz-border-radius: 100px;
        -ms-border-radius: 100px;
        -o-border-radius: 100px;
        border-radius: 100px;
      }
      .fgt-sec input[type="checkbox"] ~ label span:before {
        content: '';
        width: 7px;
        height: 7px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 100px;
        -moz-border-radius: 100px;
        -ms-border-radius: 100px;
        -o-border-radius: 100px;
        border-radius: 100px;
        font-size: 8px;
        color: #ffffff;
        opacity: 0;
        visibility: hidden;
        background-color: #e44d3a;
        position: absolute;
        font-family: fontawesome;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
        -moz-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
        -ms-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
        -o-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
        transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
      }
      .fgt-sec input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ label span:before {
        opacity: 1;
        visibility: visible;
      }
      .fgt-sec small {
        float: left;
        color: #000000;
        font-size: 14px;
        font-weight: 500;
        margin-left: 10px;
      }
      .checky-sec > a {
        float: right;
        color: #000000;
        font-size: 14px;
        font-weight: 500;
      }
      
      /* ======= Radio Button Styles ======= */
      
      .fgt-sec input[type="radio"] {
        display: none;
      }
      .fgt-sec ~ label {
        float: left;
      }
      .fgt-sec input[type="radio"] ~ label span {
        display: inline-block;
        width: 15px;
        height: 15px;
        position: relative;
        border:1px solid #d2d2d2;
        -webkit-border-radius: 100px;
        -moz-border-radius: 100px;
        -ms-border-radius: 100px;
        -o-border-radius: 100px;
        border-radius: 100px;
      }
      .fgt-sec input[type="radio"] ~ label span:before {
        content: '';
        width: 7px;
        height: 7px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 100px;
        -moz-border-radius: 100px;
        -ms-border-radius: 100px;
        -o-border-radius: 100px;
        border-radius: 100px;
        font-size: 8px;
        color: #ffffff;
        opacity: 0;
        visibility: hidden;
        background-color: #e44d3a;
        position: absolute;
        font-family: fontawesome;
        top: 49%;
        left: 49%;
        -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
        -moz-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
        -ms-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
        -o-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
        transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
      }
      .fgt-sec input[type="radio"]:checked ~ label span:before {
        opacity: 1;
        visibility: visible;
      }
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with all the CSS? Can you post an image of what you want the checkbox to look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update**

It seems that the updated code work at least in this [codepen](https://codepen.io/john-zhuangzhuang-li/pen/oNyRrXB), so perhaps in the actual project there are some other styles that are overriding the correct ones.

Not sure what might be the cause, but as requested, here is how the pseudo element works in the posted code in a nut shell:

1. The actual `input` is hidden with the following code:

```
.fgt-sec input[type="checkbox"] {
  display: none;
}
```

2. The empty check circle is a styled `span` inside a `label`, with the following code. Because this `label` has its `for` set for said `input`, clicking on it makes the `input` checked or unchecked (as if clicking on `input`).

```
  <label for="c2">
    <span></span>
  </label>
```

```
.fgt-sec input[type="checkbox"] ~ label span {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid #d2d2d2;
  -webkit-border-radius: 100px;
  -moz-border-radius: 100px;
  -ms-border-radius: 100px;
  -o-border-radius: 100px;
  border-radius: 100px;
}
```

3. The "orange dot" is a styled `::before` pseudo element (the posted code uses a shorthand `:before`) for the said `span`, it starts as invisible, as defined by the following code:

```
.fgt-sec input[type="checkbox"] ~ label span:before {
  content: "";
  width: 7px;
  height: 7px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 100px;
  -moz-border-radius: 100px;
  -ms-border-radius: 100px;
  -o-border-radius: 100px;
  border-radius: 100px;
  font-size: 8px;
  color: #ffffff;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  background-color: #e44d3a;
  position: absolute;
  font-family: fontawesome;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  -moz-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  -o-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}
```

4. When the input has a `:checked` status, the said `::before` pseudo element is set visible (so that the  "orange dot" shows up), by the following code:

```
.fgt-sec input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ label span:before {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}
```

For more detailed information, consider to check MDN pages for [CSS selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors) and [`::before`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::before).

Hope that this could help locate the error.

**Original**

It looks like this is because the `label` is styled as the next adjacent element of the original `input`. Since the pseudo element is also dependent on the styles on `label`, it disappears as the `label` is not correctly styled.

It seems to work if the additional `input` is added after `label`:

```
<div class="fgt-sec">
  <input type="checkbox" name="cc" id="c2" />
  <label for="c2">
    <span></span>
  </label>
  <!--   Additional input moved to here  -->
  <input type="hidden" name="test" />
  <small>Yes, I understand and agree to the Terms & Conditions.</small>
</div>
```

Alternatively, if the additional `input` cannot be moved, consider change the combinator in CSS from `+` to `~` so it targets the `label` correctly, as shown in below example.

[More about `~` combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_combinator)

Example:

```css
.fgt-sec {
  float: left;
}
.fgt-sec input[type="checkbox"] {
  display: none;
}
.fgt-sec label {
  float: left;
}
/*  Changed combinator to "~" here */
.fgt-sec input[type="checkbox"] ~ label span {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid #d2d2d2;
  -webkit-border-radius: 100px;
  -moz-border-radius: 100px;
  -ms-border-radius: 100px;
  -o-border-radius: 100px;
  border-radius: 100px;
}
/*  Changed combinator to "~" here */
.fgt-sec input[type="checkbox"] ~ label span:before {
  content: "";
  width: 7px;
  height: 7px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 100px;
  -moz-border-radius: 100px;
  -ms-border-radius: 100px;
  -o-border-radius: 100px;
  border-radius: 100px;
  font-size: 8px;
  color: #ffffff;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  background-color: #e44d3a;
  position: absolute;
  font-family: fontawesome;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  -moz-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  -o-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}
/*  Changed combinator to "~" here */
.fgt-sec input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ label span:before {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}
.fgt-sec small {
  float: left;
  color: #000000;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 500;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
.checky-sec > a {
  float: right;
  color: #000000;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 500;
}
```

```html
<div class="fgt-sec">
  <input type="checkbox" name="cc" id="c2" />
  <input type="hidden" name="test" />
  <label for="c2">
    <span></span>
  </label>
  <small>Yes, I understand and agree to the Terms & Conditions.</small>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi John, 
Thanks a lot for the detailed explanation. Now the checkbox is showing up as expected. But When I select the checkbox its not turning it to red as it supposed to be. If i removed the additional input element then it is turning it to red upon checking the checkbox. I am sorry I am not well versed it CSS Pseudo . I have updated my Post with additional CSS which is used for radio button. I have added the tilde symbol in those places but its still not doing anything. Can you please help.

Comment: @Saimuga It seems that the radio button is included in the updated CSS but not in HTML. Any chance it is in the same container of the checkbox? If it is, maybe try add a `class` or `id` on each `label` to help make sure the right one is selected.

Comment: Hi John,
Yes, there are two radio buttons in the html, one for sign in radio button, remember me option . another for signup radio button (I agree to terms and condition). Sorry I didnt realize the other radio button will have any effect to the issue which I am having. I have updated the code with the next radio button. Please share your thoughts.

Comment: @Saimuga I pasted your updated code into a [codepen](https://codepen.io/john-zhuangzhuang-li/pen/oNyRrXB) but both inputs seem to be working though, even with an additional hidden input added. I noticed that despite you mentioned radio button, the actual code posted has the "remember me" input as a checkbox as well. Not sure if this is intended, but it does make sense since this seems to be an option that can be checked / unchecked.

Comment: Hi John,
Sorry I meant checkbox . There is no other radio button in the page. I saw your codepen link , it is working as expected but I am really confused why its not working for me in my deployed webpage.  Can you please explain which CSS element I posted makes the checkbox turn to orange color when checked and how it changes back to white when unchecked.  I am really not sure how it is working , That is why I am not able to narrow root cause from my deployed webpage. I know how basic checkbox and radio button works but since it has pseudo elements, I am confused. Please advise.

Comment: @Saimuga I added some basic explains about how it works here, with some links for further information. Not sure if it makes sense, but hope this could help locate the error.

Comment: Hi John, Thanks a lot for all your help …. I will study your comments and links and let you know if i need any more clarification. Thanks !!!